# Search text with and without special characters in a column

Tags: sql, impala

I am running the below query:

```
select *
from db.table
where text ilike '%driver needs car%'
```

I am returning the results with the exact given words `'This cool driver needs car now'` but I want to include also special character if there are exist like this `'This cool driver, needs: car now'`. Is it possible to search also for these special characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_replace) to remove all non-alphanumeric characters.

```sql
select *
from db.table
where regexp_replace(text, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') ilike '%driver needs car%'
```